# SQL Server compare time in IF Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I am trying to compare `starttime` and `GETDATE()` time by taking there time part but in SQL Server if condition is not satisfying even though it should do by seeing .

```
IF (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 108) <= CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),(DATEADD(minute, 5, GETDATE())), 108))
BEGIN
    -- Do something 
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    -- Do Next thing
END
```

Should I convert the time to other format before comparing and using in `IF` condition ? Please help

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you mean by "compare starttime and `getdate()`".

Comment: Don't convert dates to strings if you actually want to compare the dates. You can cast to `date` to get the date part only, and `time` to get only the time part.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this code though? What it ends up doing is comparing today to itself, as long as the time is less than `23:55`

Answer (score 2):

I you want to compare the time portions, you can `cast()` your values as `time`, like:

```
cast(getdate() as time) <= cast(dateadd(minute, 5, starttime) as time)
```

The reason why you want to do this is rather unclear; beware that, with this techinque, unexpected things may happen when `starttime` has a time portion that is greater than `23:55`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: yes I see your point. As I guessed from the question, they want to compare the current time against the time on some column or variable - OP metionned `starttime`, which is what I put in my query.